# Do a javascript redirect after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to parse data to be processed on a php page and have php echo a javascript redirect to another page but it is not working. I have read that js does not work after running an ajax call so I will like to know if there s a way around it. This is my code:

html

```
<form>
    <div class="depart_time bottom_white w-40 ml-auto">
            <p>Time</p>
            <input type="time" name = "return_time" id = "rt">
    </div>
    <div class = "search_button r_search">
        <button id = "r_search" onclick = "return false" onmousedown = "rent()">SEARCH</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

ajax call is a normal xhttp request that gets sent to php for processing after which a redirection should occur:

```
if(isset($_POST['return_time'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="link.html"</script>';
}
```

Please an help is appreciated. I'm new to using ajax.

EDIT
the ajax code:

```
gid("r_search").addEventListener("mousedown", rent);
    function rent(){
        rt = gid('rt').value;
        r_search = gid('r_search').value;

        form_array = '&rt=' + rt +
        '&r_search=' + r_search;

        send_data = form_array;

        ajax_data('app/rent.php', 'error', send_data);
        //gid('error').innerHTML = send_data;
    }


function ajax_data(php_file, getId, send_data){
        gid(getId).innerHTML = "loading";
        var xhttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpReq.open("POST", php_file, true);
        xhttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                gid(getId).innerHTML = xhttpReq.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttpReq.send(send_data);
    }
```

please note that 'gid' is for getelementbyid

Comment: Can you please add code of your ajax request? You can write redirect code in your AJAX request after you get success response.

Comment: instead just send back a success/fail, then do your `window.location.href="link.html"` in the ajax callback.

Comment: @Lomtrur be careful when adding things like `<form>` to an edit, because you might have unintentionally fixed the error OP was getting. (which should be addressed as an answer instead)

Comment: That being said, you forgot to close the form in your question

Comment: @CalebGoodman The form was closed properly, but it was not visible due to weirdness with SO code formatting. I did not add it. If you check my earlier edit and look at the side-by-side markdown you can see that it was originally there. Your edit removed it, can you please fix that?

Comment: @Lomtrur How do you know the `<form>` tag is in OP's code?  What if that is the reason he is getting errors?

Comment: @CalebGoodman I know it is there because it was there when I edited the post. The code was formatted with with three grave accents. You can confirm this by checking the revisions page and clicking "side-by-side markdown" on my edit. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19ca4e88-f181-4d4f-9ee9-f44edad26581/view-source) is the source of the original revision, before any edits, which also confirms that the tag was there.

Comment: the form tag is me guys. Isn't it suppose to be there when creating a form in HTML?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the ajax code. I'm sure the form tag isn't the issue because a lot of people complained about the same thing online. Assuming it was that, It wouldn't be so hard to fix

Comment: @brown.cn yes, but I wanted to make sure that your code included the `<form>` tag, and that it wasn't the source of your problem.

Comment: OK. I read that ajax doesn't process javascript after running so I was wondering if there's a way around it

Comment: @brown.cn I'm not getting exact idea from your JS call. I want to see exact code where you have made ajax request. I guess you have written that into ajax_data(...) functions. Can you please add that code as well?

Comment: @vantiya sorry about that. I have added it now

Comment: @brown.cn I assume that every thing working from PHP side. After processing everything on PHP echo 1 if success else 0 or something whatever you like. 
After following line : gid(getId).innerHTML = xhttpReq.responseText; check if response is 1 then write window.location.href="URL where you wish to redirect page";

Comment: Ok. Been busy at work. Will try this as soon as I get home. And yes, php side is working

Comment: @Vantiya. That worked. So how do i select yours as the answer

Comment: @brown.cn I've added answer. If required let me know to edit otherwise you can accept it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make bit alteration to your way of redirection.

First you need to make changes in your PHP response

```
if(isset($_POST['return_time'])){
    ...

    // If you get your process success return 1
    if(success) { 
        echo 1; die(); 
    } else {
        // else set some flag that you could get on your AJAX response
        echo 0; die();
    }
}
```

Now, get this flag on your AJAX and make changes to your below functions:

```
function ajax_data(php_file, getId, send_data){
        gid(getId).innerHTML = "loading";
        var xhttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpReq.open("POST", php_file, true);
        xhttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if( xhttpReq.responseText == 1 ) window.location.href="URL where you wish to redirect page";
            }
        };
        xhttpReq.send(send_data);
    }
```

I've written this answer for others who come here for help.